# How to append to a value of an xml tag with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT which transforms one xml to another where I do the following simple operation.

```
    <xsl:template match="MAX/MSISDN">
        <msisdn>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </msisdn>
    </xsl:template>
```

While doing that, I want to change the value as well, from a string like

```
<msisdn>0187890567</msisdn>
```

to

```
<msisdn>90187890567</msisdn>
```

Original XML is as;

```
<MAX>
    <MSISDN>0187890567</MSISDN>
</MAX>
```

Can I do it within the same template definition? How to do it?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "Yes, you can", but can you first edit your question to show a sample of your XML, and can you confirm all you want to do is append a "9" to the start of the value? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the prefix to the template like so:

```
<xsl:template match="MAX/MSISDN">
    <msisdn>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:text>9</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </msisdn>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could have a second template to match the `text()` node and append it there

```
<xsl:template match="MAX/MSISDN">
    <msisdn>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </msisdn>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MSISDN/text()">
    <xsl:text>9</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

The latter would be prefered if you didn't want to output a `9` if the `MSISDN` element was empty

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat()` function

```
<xsl:template match="MAX/MSISDN">
    <msisdn>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('9', .)"/>
    </msisdn>
</xsl:template>
```